# Terminal show error "version solving failed. pub get failed in" in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

When I run flutter pub get then i get this error :

**Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on async 2.6.1 and fstore depends on async 2.5.0, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden.
So, because fstore depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fstore depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.)**

below shoe my all dependencies from pubspec.yml :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # Base
  pedantic: ^1.11.0
  intl: 0.17.0

  # COMMON
  inspireui:
    path: ./modules/common_library
  rubber:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/inspireui/rubber
  country_pickers:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/inspireui/country_pickers.git

  # FIREBASE PACKAGES
  firebase_core: 1.1.0
  firebase_analytics: 8.0.2
  firebase_auth: 1.1.2
  cloud_firestore: 1.0.7
  firebase_remote_config: 0.9.0-dev.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: 2.0.2
  firestore_ui:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/inspireui/firestore_ui.git

  # STATE MANAGEMENT
  provider: 5.0.0
  get_it: 6.1.1
  event_bus: 2.0.0

  # SPLASH SCREEN, ONBOARDING
  animated_splash: 1.0.0
  custom_splash: 0.0.2
  flare_splash_screen: 4.0.0
  rive: 0.7.3
  liquid_swipe: 2.1.0

  # UI
  animated_text_kit: 4.2.1
  animations: 2.0.0
  awesome_card: 1.1.5
  carousel_pro: 1.0.0
  configurable_expansion_tile: 1.0.0
  country_code_picker: 2.0.1
  flash: 1.5.2
  flutter_spinkit: 5.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.4.0
  flutter_statusbarcolor: 0.2.3
  flutter_swiper: 1.1.6
  visibility_detector: 0.2.0
  font_awesome_flutter: 9.0.0
  file_picker: 3.0.1
  page_indicator: 0.4.1
  percent_indicator: 3.0.1
  pull_to_refresh: 1.6.5
  rate_my_app: ^1.1.0+1
  cupertino_icons: any
  implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: 0.4.0
  pin_code_fields: 7.0.0


  # WEB TOOLS
  html_unescape: 2.0.0
  webview_flutter: 2.0.4
  flutter_widget_from_html: 0.6.0
  flutter_webview_plugin: 0.3.11
  responsive_builder: 0.4.1

  # MAP
  google_maps_flutter: 2.0.3
  location: 2.3.5

  # STORAGE
  localstorage: ^4.0.0+1

  # CONNECTIVITY
  http: 0.13.2
  http_auth: 1.0.0
  uni_links: 0.4.0
  share: 2.0.1

  # AUTHENTICATION
  apple_sign_in: 0.1.0
  flutter_facebook_login: 3.0.0
  google_sign_in: 5.0.2
  sms_autofill: 2.0.0

  # PUSH NOTIFICATION
  firebase_messaging: 9.1.3
  notification_permissions: 0.5.0
  onesignal_flutter: 2.6.3

  # PAYMENTS
  stripe_sdk:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/inspireui/stripe-sdk.git
  razorpay_flutter: 1.2.5

  # IMAGES
  transparent_image: 2.0.0
  extended_image: 4.0.1
  fwfh_cached_network_image: 0.6.0
  image_picker: 0.7.4
  multi_image_picker: 4.8.0
  flutter_image_compress: 1.0.0

  # VIDEOS
  video_player: 2.1.1
  youtube_player_iframe:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/inspireui/youtube_player_flutter.git
      path: packages/youtube_player_iframe

  # ADS
  facebook_audience_network: 0.7.1
  google_mobile_ads: 0.12.1+1

  # TOOLS
  auto_size_text: 2.1.0
  google_fonts: 2.0.0
  random_string: 2.1.0
  json_annotation: 4.0.1
  timeago: 3.0.2
  universal_platform: ^1.0.0-nullsafety
  uuid: 3.0.4
  validate: 1.7.0
  vector_math: any
  async: 2.5.0
  easy_debounce: 2.0.0
  charts_flutter: 0.10.0
  devicelocale: ^0.4.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    version: any
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  test: any
  flutter_launcher_icons: 0.8.1
  mockito: ^4.1.1 # Testing
#  vm_service: 5.5.0

## Enable To run json serializer, run:
## flutter pub run build_runner build --build-filter="lib/models/serializers/*.dart" --delete-conflicting-outputs
## flutter pub run build_runner serve --build-filter="lib/models/serializers/*.dart"
#  build_runner: 1.12.2
#  json_serializable: 4.1.0

### Override the library to support Flutter 2.0
### Note: This will show the warning but will not impact to the app features 
dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.17.0
  http: 0.13.2
  crypto: 3.0.1
  path_provider: 2.0.1
  uuid: 3.0.4
  http_parser: 4.0.0
  pedantic: 1.11.0
  flutter_svg: 0.19.3
  url_launcher: 6.0.1
  cached_network_image: 2.5.1
  modal_bottom_sheet: 2.0.0
  args: 2.1.0
```

Comment: Checkout : https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After add async 2.6.1 to dependency_overrides: in pubspec.yml it solved

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with firebase dependencies. Try removing one dependency at a time and distinguish the one which is causing the issue. According to my understanding, the error is most probably with firestore.

Comment: which dependency ?  firestore_ui  or any other?

Comment: It's either firestore_ui or cloud_firestore. The problem is with the dependencies. If it's not either of the 2, which I am guessing it should be, then you will need to check each one separately. Also, can you tell me, which device are you testing on?

Comment: I tring on windows system and editor android studio

Comment: not work after remove both firestore dependency

Comment: So, because fstore depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed. This is the error. Flutter driver is causing to be the problem. You need to mention which flutter driver. It says that your app depends on flutter driver any. Try mentioning a version of flutter driver.